# How to add name in JSONPATH

Tags: javascript, json

I have an array like this

```
{
    "activities": [
        {
            "activityId": "60f672b20f38640008a6c29b",
            "_id": "610cb887b149cb00095e1eb6",
            "trackingProgress": [
                {
                    "_id": "610cb8ee541fea0009189c36",
                    "dateRecorded": "2021-07-16T00:00:00.000Z",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "_id": "610cb8ee541fea0009189c37",
                            "feelingType": "Satisfied",
                            "times": 2
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "_id": "611358300fea490008d56ea7",
                    "dateRecorded": "2021-08-10T00:00:00.000Z",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "_id": "6113583b0fea490008d56eae",
                            "feelingType": "Neutral",
                            "times": 1
                        }
                    ]
                },
                {
                    "_id": "611b6068fed9100009a4f689",
                    "dateRecorded": "2021-08-17T00:00:00.000Z",
                    "items": [
                        {
                            "_id": "611b6068fed9100009a4f68a",
                            "feelingType": "Satisfied",
                            "times": 4
                        }
                    ]
                }
            ],
            "title": "Losing & Managing Weight",
            "description": "Losing weight",
            "order": null,
            "daysOfWeek": [
                "tuesday"
            ],
            "reminderTimeAt": "09:00 am",
            "type": "Custom",
            "progressOverview": {
                "notSatisfied": 0,
                "neutral": 1,
                "satisfied": 6
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

I use [JSONPATH](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath) to get `_id` in `items`

```
$.activities.[*].trackingProgress.[*].items[*].[_id]
```

it return an array like this

```
[
  "610cb8ee541fea0009189c37",
  "6113583b0fea490008d56eae",
  "611b6068fed9100009a4f68a"
]
```

But, i want to keep the "_id", something like :

```
[
  "_id":"610cb8ee541fea0009189c37",
  "_id":"6113583b0fea490008d56eae",
  "_id":"611b6068fed9100009a4f68a"
]
```

How can i do that?? Thank you a lots, i search internet but i found nothing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you use `map`, you can get an array of items that each have an `_id` and value.

```
let result = [
  "610cb8ee541fea0009189c37",
  "6113583b0fea490008d56eae",
  "611b6068fed9100009a4f68a"
].map(i => ({"_id": i}))
```

Results in:

```
[{ _id: "610cb8ee541fea0009189c37" }, 
 { _id: "6113583b0fea490008d56eae" },
 { _id: "611b6068fed9100009a4f68a" }]
```

Comment: @lê-quốc-khánh It's important to note here that what you're looking for is transformation (creation of a new JSON value).  JSON Path doesn't support this; it's just a 
query language.  You'll need additional logic for building the value you want.